# How to retrieve trained hyperparameters from sklearn GaussianProcessRegressor model

Tags: scikit-learn

Calling `model.fit(X,y); model.get_params()` returns the values that I initialized my kernels with.  How do I get the hyperparameters of the trained model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `model.get_params()` as mentioned [in documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.get_params) will return the parameters passed into the initialization of the GPR.

It optimizes the passed kernel's internal parameters which is available using **`model.kernel_`**.

See the documentation and associated examples for more details.

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gaussian-process-regression-gpr
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_co2.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-gpr-co2-py